# I want to get the message on which the user is reacted inside the on_reaction_add function in discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

**I want to create a meme bot with a reaction in the meme message, whenever a person clicks on the reaction the bot will send the meme in his/her dm.
And I can't able to find a way to do that!
Anyone can help me?**

```
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  if user != client.user:
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "➡️":
```

Comment: You can use [`reaction.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction.message)

Comment: no i can't it says <Message id=903955341660803162 channel=<TextChannel id=888695267447152660 name='-' position=5 nsfw=False news=False category_id=888693369218428948> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=888726151449690153 name='Manager' discriminator='7174' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=888689763832438845 name='Developers' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=26>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>

Comment: What do you mean you can't? `reaction.message` gives you the `message` object. If you want the actual content, then use `reaction.message.content`

Comment: it always returns "None"

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

For starters, use the `on_raw_reaction_add` event, which also detects reactions added to posts that are not in your bot's cache => https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add

Then, you first check that it's not your bot that adds the reaction, if it is, you stop the function. Then, you have several solutions. I would make a sqlite database where I would store each meme posted with the link and the id of the message. And so in your event you look if the post id where your reaction is added is in your database, and if yes you send in dm the link linked to the id.